# Can't properly redirect unsuccessful login on laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I'm making an app in Laravel 5.2.
I'm trying to implement an auth page for the backoffice.

In routes  I've got a group and auth middleware:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function () {
    Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
        Route::get('/', 'IndexController@admin_index')->name('admin_index');
        Route::get('/logout', 'IndexController@admin_logout')->name('logout');
    });

    Route::get('/login', 'UsersController@admin_login')->name('login');
});
```

What I want to accomplish here is when I enter "/admin", if a user is logged, redirect to "/", if not, redirect to "/admin/login"

The current behavior is redirect to "/login" on unsuccessful login, how can I change that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't have any other auth-protected pages for regular users, you could simply modify Authenticate middleware, otherwise you probably need to extend Auth middleware to add support for multiple redirect points

Option 1, modifying middleware:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->guest()) {
            if ($request->ajax() || $request->wantsJson()) {
                return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
            } else {
                // Changing login to admin/login
                return redirect()->guest('admin/login');
            }
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

Option 2 - create one more auth middleware, let's say 'auth-admin', change handle() method of that as shown above, and apply that middleware to admin routes instead of 'auth' middleware.

Option 3 - add a conditional in handle() method

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->guest()) {
            if ($request->ajax() || $request->wantsJson()) {
                return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
            } else {
                $destination = (strpos($request->path(), 'admin') !== false) ? 'admin/login' : 'login';
                return redirect()->guest($destination);
            }
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

Comment: I undestood that $redirectTo is for when you successfully login, is that correct?

Comment: @AguV sorry, my bad. $redirectTo is indeed for successful login, unauthorised redirects are handled in the middleware directly, see updated answer

Comment: A little comment, I've tryied and is  (strpos($request->path(), 'admin') because path is a function not a property.

Comment: @AguV oops you are right :) I wrote the code right here on SO, my IDE would have fixed the error automatically :)